# Using VLOOKUP with data in nonadjacent columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have my data stored in

[image: one sheet]

and

[image: another sheet]

I want to pull a subset of that data based on the selection in a dropdown. For example, if I select "Org 1" in the dropdown, then all the indicator data (Indicators 1-15 will populate) next to the label for that indicator. I know how to do this when the data is adjacent -- with the names of the orgs in a column that is next to the corresponding data. For this, I have used the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,'Data Lookup 1718'!A3:B16,2,FALSE)
```

However, this means that in the worksheet with my data I need to replicate the column of orgs 15 times so that the org names are always next to the indicator data. Is there another way to do this--preferably a formula that will allow me to pull data from nonadjacent cells? I've attached my data for reference. Thank you!

Comment: Is the dropdown in `C1`? What about the Indicators, where are those? And where is the non-adjacent data? This question is unclear to anyone who can't see your spreadsheet. Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1385028/edit) to provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sorry for that -- I was not able to attach the Excel sheet but have attached some screenshots. Yes, the dropdown is in C1. Hopefully the screenshots make it more clear but please let me know if not and I can add more details. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(C$1,'Data Lookup 1718'!A$3:P$16,ROW()-1,FALSE)
```

This is the same VLOOKUP you are using with two changes:

1) Use the entire data table (I assumed it ends at column `P` since there are 15 indicators.

2) Use the row the formula is in (`ROW()`) as the basis for the index of the column to use in the `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'm not sure I understand the 2nd item. The formulas are in the H column. What row should I be referencing in the formula?

Comment: `=ROW()` returns the row it is typed in (try it!). The formula is using the fact that it is in a different row for each indicator to access the different columns in the `Data Lookup 1718` worksheet

Answer (score 0):

to refer to non-adjacent columns (2) in a large table (>2 columns) I found a simple intuitive method of finding the column number of both using COLUMN(). Once you know both column numbers, you say:

column2 - column1 + [number of columns before column1]

in order to achieve the col_index_num.

This is necessary because it maintains the column numbers even if columns are removed or added! With this formula, you may choose the entire table_array and consistently use VLOOKUP to find values in non-adjacent columns as we have found a formula to determine the column to be looked up.

I was using this formula between worksheets as well, and I just got it to work.

I hope this helps,

Sahil Govender